# How to link a tab bar with its view controllers in a storyboard?

Tags: ios

If you've only ever used a tab bar controller and not a tab bar on its own, then don't close this or mark it as a duplicate based upon your presumptions and assumptions.

I've added a tab bar to a view controller and now want to connect the tab bar with the view controllers that will be selected via it.

I've done this sort of thing many, many times before using a tab bar controller and assumed it would be just as straightforward as but when a using just a tab bar but no - I just can't find or see any way of doing it. Tried adding tab bar items to the view controller and tried dragging between these and the tab bar, and between the tab bar and the tab bar items and to the view controllers. Millions of combinations and can't get it to work.

Googling or searching for past questions on this isn't as straightforward as you'd think - because the search results all come back involving the use of a tab bar controller, I can't see anything for just a tab bar which is part of a regular view controller.

Comment: Why don't you use a `UITabBarController`?

Comment: Because I want to combine a navigation bar controller and a tab bar and I don't want to have the navigation controller embedded in the tab bar controller as I don't want that as the rvc.

Comment: Then add a `UITabBarController` as a view controller to the navigation controller.

Comment: If you combine a navigation bar controller and a tab bar controller the apple documentation states you must put the tab bar controller as the rvc and not the navigation bar controller.

Comment: Then you have to implement your own tab bar controller using a container view controller.

Comment: "have to" ? You're stating categorically it is impossible to have a navigation bar controller and then add a tab bar to it?

Comment: No, I don't. If you do this, you can't link the view controller in the storyboard. See my answer.

Comment: I have an app in the App Store that uses an `UITabBarController` inside an `UINavigationController` and I've never had a problem with this. I've never heard of the Apple Docs saying otherwise. I'd like to see it though.

Comment: Here it says "When combining these two types of view controller .. the tab bar controller always acts as the wrapper for the navigation controllers". https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html  I've seen other sources saying there's problems if done otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is not possible using a storyboard. You should do this in code.

Or maybe `hideBottomBarWhenPushed` is what you are searching for.